# Conjugate of compact Lie subgroup strictly contained in itself

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

I'm currently reading the book "Lie Groups and Geometric Aspects of Isometric Actions" by Alexandrino and Bettiol and I'm having problems understanding a particular argument on page 73, Proposition 3.74:
$M$ is supposed to be a Riemannian manifold on which the Lie group $G$ acts properly and isometrically.
And for $x, y \in M$ we denote by $G_x, G_y$ the respective isotropy subgroups (which of course are compact).
What I don't understand: Why does $g G_x g^{-1} \subset G_y \subset G_x$ already imply that there must be equalities everywhere?

To put it more generally: Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a compact subgroup and suppose that $g H g^{-1} \subset H$ for some $g \in G$. Why is it true that $g H g^{-1} = H$?
Of course, for a finite group this is trivial but I have seen examples for infinite groups where this property fails.

Comment: I would bet it has to do with the specific topology of isotropy groups, not just that they're compact. E.g. an injective, continuous map from a sphere to itself must be a homeomorphism (I think). I assume the same may be true of orthogonal groups.

Comment: Let $F=gHg^{-1}$.
If $H$ is connected, then $F$ is also connected. Since $H$ and $F$ are isomorphic, $\dim(H)=\dim(F)$. Since $F<H$, it follows that $H=F$. If $H$ is not connected and $H_0$ is a  connected component of $H$, then $H_0=F_0$ and $|H/H_0|=|F/F_0|<\varnothing$. It follows that $H=F$.

Comment: Correction. $$|H/H_0|=|F/F_0|<\infty$$